# How do I get results?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I write the following code, I also write `console.log()`, and I do not get results, can someone help me and explain to me why I can't get results?

```js
function integers() {
    let MyArray;
    MyArray = [];

    for (let i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
        MyArray.push(i);
    }
    console.log(MyArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript functions are not being called automatically. If you need to do so, You can create an auto call function -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10704006/7078456

Or you can manually call your function to get the output of your function.

```
function integers() {
    let myArray = [];

    for (let i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
        myArray.push(i);
    }

    console.log(myArray);
}

integers()
```

Comment: This is a code-dump answer, one that offers no explanation for the problem, the code, how the code solves the problem, in other words, an answer that is not helpful to future visitors to this site, which is the entire purpose of this site.

Comment: I would suggest that you edit and fix the answer, but since this question and your answer will likely be deleted in a few days' time, there is probably no need in this situation. But for future reference, please gear your answers so that they are written for the benefit of *future* visitors with similar problems.